# Mock patch a variable's method

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest, monkeypatching

I have a method in a class Object that I want to test that looks roughly like this:

```
def method():
    pm = get_parameter(p)
    value = pm.get_value()
    if value:
        return pm.calculate()
```

Now I want to mock the pm.get_value to always return true, but I don't know the path to use...
**pm** is an object of class Parameter but patching "Parameter.get_value" doesn't help, because you have to patch a function where it's used.
However patching "Object.get_value" doesn't work either because Object doesn't have an attribute get_value.

I hope my explanation is clear enough?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why are you not patching `Parameter.get_value`?

Comment: Typo, my bad.
I tried that, but patching has to be done in the class where the method is used, not where it's created, right?

Comment: It seems `get_parameter ` is implementing a Factory pattern. You can mock it by returning a mock object where is mocking `pm`.

However, in my opinion, I would inject the `pm` instances throw the method, which then would be easier to test the method. You will need only to pass the `pm` mock object via parameter, instead of the real one.

Comment: Please provide `get_parameter` code.